# OpenCV 2.4.13 missing opencv_core2413d.dll in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am starting to use opencv for my project but I experienced some issue when setting up it in vs 2012.

I download OpenCV 2.4.13. I go through a lot of tutorial but I got an error saying that

```
The program can't start because opencv_core2413d.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem
```

Here is all my steps to setup:

1) setup Windows environment variable, Path to "C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin"

2) Open an empty project in vs 2012, change the configuration manager to 64 bit platform.

3) Then add "C:\opencv\build\include" and "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv" in VC++ Directories -> Include Directories

4) Add "C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11" in VC++ Directories -> Library Directories

5) Switch to C/C++ -> General -> additional include directories, add "C:\opencv\build\include"

6) Add "C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib" to Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

7) Add the following to Link -> Input -> additional dependencies

```
opencv_core2413d.lib
opencv_calib3d2413d.lib
opencv_contrib2413d.lib
opencv_features2d2413d.lib
opencv_highgui2413d.lib
opencv_imgproc2413d.lib
```

Here is my test main to use openCV

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv ){ 
    Mat image;
    if( argc != 2){
        cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        image = imread("HappyMan's Girl.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        // Read the file
    }
    else{
        image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    }

    if(! image.data ){// Check for invalid input
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << endl ;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "HappyMan - Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    // Create a window for display.
    imshow( "HappyMan - Display window", image );
    // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);
    // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Can I get some help on this?

Thanks

---

updated my system variables settings image:

[image]

Comment: Does `opencv_core2413d.dll`  exist in `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin`? If so did you reboot since you modified the system path?

Comment: @drescherjm I checked the path, the file exists. I tried rebooting but the error still there. I did not get compile error but when I ran in debug mode, it pop that error up

Comment: your  steps look ok.. can you post your path variable? Can you copy the application binary to the opencv bin directory and start it there?

Comment: @Micka I found  that if I place all dll in system32 and it will work. I am wondering is there any disadvantages to do that?

Comment: It's no good style (especially the debug libraries). Better put them correctly to your PATH variable or put them to the buil/target directory and choose that to be your working directory of the debugger.

Comment: This means your modification of the windows system path variable was wrong.

Comment: Updated my environment variable image to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

Just paste the dll files in your project directory where .exe file is present and you will be good to go.
Another method is to paste the .dll files in System32 folder( haven't tried it though)
eg C:\Users\Reaper\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug
Hope this helps